# Laravel passport auth token not working after moving to different server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have created this small app using laravel + vue js 2 years ago. It has been working fine till now but the server guys moved it to different server and suddenly I have started getting "unauthenticated" error on all pages.

The login form works and it generates the personal access token nicely, but when I use that personal access token anywhere on this portal like this "Bearer MY_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN", it doesn't work.

Is there any additional step I have to do after moving the files to different server? The URL are all same, its just the server is changed. I have also tried running `php artisan passport:install` but it doesn't fix the issue. I have hundreds of user accounts stored on this DB and now they are unable to use any features.

Any idea how I sort this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in your .htaccess on your server files.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) 
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing this into the console?

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: Just tried it, it generates new app key but that didn't make any difference

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: Did you copy the vendor and node_modules files or did you install them again by npm install or composer install?

Comment: I installed them again

Comment: I have a feeling that it has something to do with passport. because the user login using username and password works fine and then it generates access token. this token is not getting authenticated in the rest of the app.